# Struct inside union inside struct in c

Tags: c, struct, malloc, unions

hello lets say i have this code

```
typedef struct entry {
    union {
        struct A {
            char  *c;
        } *A;
        struct B {
            char *c;
        } *B;
    } value;
} *TableEntry;
```

i m doing a malloc for entry and now i want to copy a string to c from struct A . do i have to allocate memory for struct A and then for c or the first malloc for table entry allocates for all of them ? thank you in advance

Comment: @Malloc: How's this not C++?

Comment: Its not C++. You can argue that C is a subset of C++, and you would be wrong.

Comment: @littleadv: It is valid C++, so give a **good** reason to remove the tag.

Comment: @Deduplicator as I said - you can argue that and you would be wrong. One good reason: the OP said its C.

Comment: @littleadv: Where? See no such statement.

Comment: @Deduplicator Look at the title.

Comment: @Deduplicator in the title of the question may be?

Comment: Ok, reacted to strongly on seeing those cannot be C++ assertions. The title says the OP is only interested in C. That's the only C specific part of the question and all answers though.

Answer (score 3):

you have to allocate memory for both of them

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate the `TableEntry` - you allocate the memory for the whole union. Pointers in it are allocated, but what they point to - are not. So you should assign values that you allocate to `c` members of the struct and `A`/`B` members of the union.

Note that the `A` and `B` share the same space.

Comment: so we have a malloc for the whole struct and then only for c is that right ?

Comment: @user3187860 yes. And you only allocate one struct, either A or B - you cannot have both.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, three allocs are needed, e.g.:

```
TableEntry *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
t->A = malloc(sizeof *t->A);
t->A->c = malloc(50);
```

This design is questionable though, as there is no way of telling which is currently active out of `A` or `B`. You will have to have another index or something which keeps track of whether this entry is an `A` or a `B`.